# Where can i download a good World image in GeoTIFF?

Tags: imagery

I can either be from MERIS (ESA) or from MODIS (Nasa). I already reached these sites:

http://www.unearthedoutdoors.net/global_data/true_marble/download

http://www.eosnap.com/public/mosri/2009/world/world-mosaic-final-100.jpg

But from the first I was not able to download, and from the second it is not available in tiff.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "good"? Which resolution?

Comment: 4km would be ok (REF: http://www.unearthedoutdoors.net/global_data/true_marble/download).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=57752

...and pick your resolution with images from 2MB to 401MB

Comment: those are not geotiff

Comment: You can use gdal_translate on those to get a decent-looking world map. The whole thing took about an hour fumbling around.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to georeference an [xglobe](http://www.radcyberzine.com/xglobe/index.html#maps) image using [`gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

```
gdal_translate -a_srs WGS84 -a_ullr -180 +90 +180 -90 xglobe-2400.jpg xglobe-2400.tiff
```

Answer (score 4):

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) offers free vector and raster map data at 1:10m, 1:50m, and 1:110m scales.

For example: [global satellite-derived land cover data (.tif file) and shaded relief available with ocean bottom data, or without](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-1/).

Answer (score 1):

True Marble Free Download

*Download and use the **250m True Marble global** dataset for free! This is a low resolution version of our full 15m product, but it is quite useful. Download to use on your web page or preview a purchase. We only ask that you display our copyright and reference this page when using it.
Two types of files are available for download: GeoTIFF and PNG. The GeoTIFF files are better suited for GIS programs, but are generally a larger file size. The PNG files are for general image processing programs, but are not georeferenced. Most of these files are much too large for your web browser to display, so be sure to save the file directly to disk.*

or the Premium Product 15m Resolution
Global Coverage $125,000

Note: It cost's a lot of money to get a Satellite built of the ground and into orbit hence the price.

Comment: this is the link I posted in the question. Download isn't working, at least for me.

Comment: Do you have a budget?

Comment: nop :) It's not critical

Comment: Downloads don't work for me either. I get a 2kb .gz file which doesn't extract.

Comment: Try the GeoTiff torrent

Comment: Any luck in lightening those images? When I tried to make em lighter it became apparent the halves of the globe have slightly different coloring when the transparency and/or gamma is turned up. I'd probably be able to budget the paid version of the map but it is rough on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The True Marble site looks down – But fortunately the page is [archived on the internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021232144/http://www.unearthedoutdoors.net/global_data/true_marble/download) including all(?) files, and also the torrent files. Downloading the huge files from archive.org can be slow, so you want to use [the torrent](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021232144/http://www.unearthedoutdoors.net/global_data/true_marble/TrueMarble_GeoTIFF.torrent).

There is also an [improved version](https://github.com/lyrk/true-marble-edit) of true marble available. Clouds and merge-errors are removed in this version. Also Svalbard was added.

Comment: None of the above hyperlinks seems to work. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Now even the internet archive is down.

You can download zipped 250m Blue Marble tiff images in 45° x 45° tiles from [here](http://geospatialearth.in/BM.php).

There are total 32 zipped files for the whole world.